# sql developer ORA-00905 "missins keyword" message

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

i just started learning sql and i tried to create the next table and everytime the "missins keyword" message appears, someone have an idea about what i did wrong?

```
create table Ingresos(
codIngreso varchar2(6) not null,
fechaIngreso date,
costeIngreso number(9),
constraint ingresos_pk primary key(codIngreso),
constraint rut_pac_fk foreign key(rutPac),
constraint num_sala_fk foreign key(numSala)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `REFERENCES` keyword in the foreign key constraints and the details of which table and column the constraint is references.

```sql
create table Ingresos(
codIngreso varchar2(6) not null,
fechaIngreso date,
costeIngreso number(9),
constraint ingresos_pk primary key(codIngreso),
constraint rut_pac_fk  foreign key(rutPac)  REFERENCES other_table1(other_column1),
constraint num_sala_fk foreign key(numSala) REFERENCES other_table2(other_column2)
)
```

That will fix the missing keyword error; however, you will then get the error `ORA-00904: "RUTPAC": invalid identifier` as your table does not define the `rutPac` or `numSala` columns that are referenced in the foreign key constraints so you will need to solve that as well (probably by creating those columns in the table).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5rr_DpuJ)